# How to reset QFile/ QTextStream?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am getting a file to be reset after a first read. All googling hasn't helped at all.

How do I reset a file to it's begin after it has been read a first time?

Trial one:

```
        inFile = QFile( self._pathFileName )
        inFile.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text)
        stream = QTextStream(inFile)
        
        # Count first all lines in the file
        self._numLinesRead = 0
        self._mumLinesTotal = 0
        while not stream.atEnd():
            self._mumLinesTotal=+1
            stream.readLine();
        
        inFile.seek(0)
        stream.seek(0) 
        pos = stream.pos()   # pos is equal to 0 after this line verified with debugging
        
        while( not stream.atEnd() ):  # but here it still thinks he's at file end and jumps over
            ....
```

Trial two:

```
        inFile = QFile( self._pathFileName )
        inFile.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text)
        stream = QTextStream(inFile)
        
        # Count first all lines in the file
        self._numLinesRead = 0
        self._mumLinesTotal = 0
        while not stream.atEnd():
            self._mumLinesTotal=+1
            stream.readLine();
        inFile.close()
        
        del inFile
        del stream
        inFile = QFile( self._pathFileName )
        inFile.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text)
        stream = QTextStream(inFile)
        # everyting has been reset?!
        
        while( not stream.atEnd() ):  # Nop it still thinks it is atEnd and jumps over
            ....
```

I tried all the solutions found in the net. Nothing helps. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Uhm. That's strange, especially with the second case. Have you tried different files? Are those text files written on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what I should say, but after a complete reboot of the system "Trial two" worked.

After a second reboot (two days and a lot of code changes later) also "Trial one" came to life.

After all: both trials are from my point of view valid and working.

If in case you discover strange behaviour during development and debugging try a reboot.